# Ngram Tokenizer for files in Java

Tags: java, file, token, n-gram

my goal is to create a program that takes in a file, reads it, parses it into tokens and spits back out the index with the relative and absolute frequency. I understand how to tokenize regular strings, however, I do not understand how to do it with files. Furthermore, I do not understand where my ngram class can go in with all of this. Additionally, is there an easier way to count the words? I know I sound stupid, and I'm sorry if this is dumb question, but I really need help. I'm so lost and this code isn't making anymore sense.

Here is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        File file = new File("jarg2912.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Index:");
        //System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        //NgramIterator ngram = new NgramIterator(0, "jarg2912.txt");
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fileReader.getEncoding());
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public class NgramIterator implements Iterator<String> {

String[] line;
int position = 0, number;

public NgramIterator(int n, String str) {
    this.number = n;
    this.line = str.split(" ");
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return position < line.length - number + 1;
}

@Override
public String next() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = position; i < position + number; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append((i > position ? " " : "") + line[i]);
        position++;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what is in the jarg2912.txt file?

Comment: Also can you give examples of the expected output, because it is not very clear what you want

Comment: I am supposed to output an index of the words in a document and list the amount of times they appear

Comment: and what is that index? how do you calculate it? what does it represent? And what is in the file?